# How to inject Database into constructor with Laravel IoC

Tags: php, laravel, pdo, laravel-4, inversion-of-control

I want to use DB class for transaction with IoC Container.

```
use Illuminate\Database\Connection as DB;
public function __construct(DB $db)
{
    $this->db = $db;
}
```

But when use db class,i got an error.

```
Unresolvable dependency resolving [Parameter #0 [ <required> $dsn ]] in class PDO
```

I know, must bind something but i don't know what?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to change

```
use Illuminate\Database\Connection as DB;
```

into

```
use Illuminate\Database\DatabaseManager as DB;
```

I thought you can use `DB` facade here but in fact you can't. You need to explicitly pass here class that is behind the facade looking at http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/facades#facade-class-reference

Comment: I cant use Facade because return this error :  ```Call to undefined method Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB::beginTransaction()```