# Interface with DB Facade in Laravel

Tags: php, design-patterns, laravel-5.5

First, I apologize if this is a stupid question. I recently read an article about repository design pattern and I have a problem when making interface implementation for Laravel Query Builder (Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB).

**DatabaseService.php**

```
use Modules\Core\Interfaces\IDatabase;
use \DB;

class DatabaseService implements IDatabase
{  
  protected $db;

  public function __construct(DB $db)
  {
    $this->db = $db;
  }

  public function select($str)
  {
    $this->db::select($str);
    return $this->db;
  }

  public function table($tableName)
  {
    $this->db::table($tableName);
    return $this->db;
  }

  ...
}
```

**IDatabase.php**

```
<?php namespace Modules\Core\Interfaces;
interface IDatabase
{
  public function select($str);
  public function table($tableName);
  public function raw($rawQuery);
  public function transaction($callback);
  public function first();
  public function get();
}
```

**CoreServiceProvider.php**

```
...

public function register()
{
  ...
  $this->app->bind('Modules\Core\Interfaces\IDatabase', function($app) {
    $db = $app->make(DB::class);

    return new DatabaseService($db);
  });
  ...
}
```

**MailboxRepository.php**

```
<?php namespace Modules\Mailbox\Repositories;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Modules\Core\Interfaces\IDatabase;
use Modules\Mailbox\Interfaces\IMailbox;

class MailboxRepository implements IMailbox
{
  public function __construct(..., IDatabase $db)
  {
  ...
    $this->db = $db;
  }
  ...
  public function getBadges()
  {
    $badges = $this->db->table('mailbox as a')
              ->select($this->db->raw(
                "SUM(a.type = 'inbox') as inbox, 
                 SUM(a.is_read = 0 AND a.type = 'inbox') as unread,
                 SUM(a.type = 'sent') as sent,
                 SUM(a.type = 'draft') as draft,
                 SUM(a.type = 'outbox') as outbox,
                 SUM(a.type = 'spam') as spam,
                 SUM(a.type = 'trash') as trash,
                 SUM(a.is_starred = 1) as starred"
              ))
              ->first();

    return $badges;
  }
  ...
}
```

**MailboxServiceProvider.php**

```
<?php namespace Modules\Mailbox;

...
use Modules\Mailbox\Interfaces\IMailbox;
use Modules\Mailbox\Repositories\MailboxRepository;
use Modules\Core\Interfaces\IDatabase;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class MailboxServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider 
{
  protected $defer = true;

  public function register()
  {
    $this->app->bind(IMailbox::class, function($app) {
      return new MailboxRepository(
        ..., $app->make(IDatabase::class)
      );
    });
  }

  public function provides()
  {
    return [IMailbox::class];
  }
}
```

With error message :

```
[2018-01-31 13:45:04] local.ERROR: Call to undefined method Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB::select() 
{"userId":1,"email":"info@narpandi.com","exception":"[object] 
(Symfony\\Component\\Debug\\Exception\\FatalThrowableError(code: 0): Call 
to undefined method Illuminate\\Support\\Facades\\DB::select() at 
/var/www/personal-
website/app/Modules/Mailbox/Repositories/MailboxRepository.php:86)
```

How to do this correctly? Thank you for your kind help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trial and error, I finally figure out how to do this. As mentioned in https://stackoverflow.com/a/26356144/3050636, you cannot use facade DB directly so instead you need to explicitly pass class that is behind the DB facade.

In my case, I use bridge pattern and fluent interface (CMIIW) so I will provide two versions:

- Without bridge pattern

**MailboxServiceProvider.php**

```
<?php namespace Modules\Mailbox;

use Modules\Mailbox\Interfaces\IMailbox;
...
use Modules\Mailbox\Repositories\MailboxRepository;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

/* Use these instead of DB facade */
use Illuminate\Database\DatabaseManager;
use Illuminate\Database\Connectors\ConnectionFactory;

class MailboxServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider 
{
  protected $defer = true;

  public function register()
  {
    $this->app->bind(IMailbox::class, function($app) {
      return new MailboxRepository(
        ..., new DatabaseManager($app, new ConnectionFactory($app))
      );
    });
  }

  public function provides()
  {
    return [IMailbox::class];
  }
}
```

**MailboxRepository.php**

```
<?php namespace Modules\Mailbox\Repositories;

use Illuminate\Database\DatabaseManager;
use Modules\Mailbox\Interfaces\IMailbox;

class MailboxRepository implements IMailbox
{
  ...
  protected $db;

  public function __construct(..., DatabaseManager $db)
  {
    ...
    $this->db = $db;
  }
  ...
}
```

- With bridge pattern and fluent interface

**CoreServiceProvider.php**

```
<?php namespace Modules\Core;

....
use Modules\Core\Services\DatabaseService;
use Modules\Mailbox\Repositories\MailboxRepository;
use Modules\Core\Interfaces\IDatabase;
use Modules\Mailbox\Interfaces\IMailbox;

/* Use these instead of DB facade */
use Illuminate\Database\DatabaseManager;
use Illuminate\Database\Connectors\ConnectionFactory;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class CoreServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider 
{
  public function register()
  {
    ...
    $this->app->bind(IDatabase::class, function($app) {
      return new DatabaseService(new DatabaseManager($app, new ConnectionFactory($app)));
    });

    $this->app->bind(IMailbox::class, function($app) {
      return new MailboxRepository(
        ..., $app->make(IDatabase::class)
      );
    });
    ...
  }
}
```

**DatabaseService.php**

```
<?php namespace Modules\Core\Services;

use Modules\Core\Interfaces\IDatabase;
use Illuminate\Database\DatabaseManager;

class DatabaseService implements IDatabase
{  
  protected $db;

  public function __construct(DatabaseManager $db)
  {
    $this->db = $db;
  }

  public function select($str)
  {
    $this->db = $this->db->select($str);
    return $this->db;
  }

  public function table($tableName)
  {
    $this->db = $this->db->table($tableName);
    return $this->db;
  }
  ...
}
```

**MailboxRepository.php**

```
<?php namespace Modules\Mailbox\Repositories;

use Modules\Core\Interfaces\IDatabase;
use Modules\Mailbox\Interfaces\IMailbox;

class MailboxRepository implements IMailbox
{
  ...
  protected $db;

  public function __construct(..., IDatabase $db)
  {
    ...
    $this->db = $db;
  }
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is a common repository pattern, in repository pattern you try to create methods like:

```
Object get(Object id);
void create(Object entity);
void update(Object entity);
void delete(Object entity);
```

Edit, try to do something like docs: [Database](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/database#running-queries)

```
use Modules\Core\Interfaces\IDatabase;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

class DatabaseService implements IDatabase
{  

  public function select($str, $args)
  {
    return DB::select($str, $args);
  }
}
```

But i say again this doesn't look like a `repository`.

Comment: I'm sorry for bad naming. I use `IDatabase` constructor similar to your second option in MailboxController which in this case I only put my query for the sake of simplicity. I'll edit my post and try changing method name as suggested. Thank you for the answer.

Comment: Edit: Sorry for missing detail, I have updated my code. Thank you

Comment: In your DatabaseService you are calling ``$this->db::select($str)``. Is there such method in ``DB`` class? Sorry, long time since last used laravel.

Comment: I'm not sure to be honest. My code are only based on assumption since I don't know how to do correctly. The problem is object that I want to bind to `IDatabase` is Facade and if I can pass Facade object correctly in `MailboxServiceProvider.php`, I can omit `DatabaseService.php`

Comment: It says ``select`` method take 2 parameters: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/database#running-queries try with an empty array

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, still not working and the error now moved to `table()` method. I found  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26355695/how-to-inject-database-into-constructor-with-laravel-ioc but didn't working with Laravel 5. I probably need to ask another question. Thank you for your time.

Comment: If the problem change to ``table()`` clearly the ``select()`` now it's ok, Did you try to use ``DB::table`` instead of  ``this->$db::table()`` like in select method?

Comment: Table problem part was my mistake because I pass a wrong table name. Injecting a facade was a mistake so I post the solution regarding to this issue.